# output array in right way

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I use ZF1, and i need to put in title this if:

```
title="<?php echo isset($this->region['klu']) ? $this->region['klu'] : 'region name for  klu'?>"
```

where klu - is a data in r_alias row in my table

So, in my Controller i do something like this:

```
$region = Map_Model_Map_Factory::getFetchAll();
        $this->view->assign('region', $region);
```

What is getFetchAll():

```
static function getFetchAll()
    {
        $table = new Map_Model_Map_Table();
        $select = $table->select()
                        ->order('r_alias ASC');
        return $table->fetchAll($select);
    }
```

but something going wrong here, i need to have my echo region, instead i have empty page.

Comment: What is klu? The name of a column inside your table?

Comment: Using `fetchAll()` you get multiple rows (a `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` object); however, your code suggests that you assume it is a single row (by accessing 'klu' directly). Do you expect `$this->region` to contain a single row, or multiple rows?

Comment: r_id  r_c_id  r_name  r_name_en  r_alias
1  2       Клузен  Kluzen          klu

Comment: Do you want all region names to display? Or only the region name of the first row?

Comment: @stopper please check updated answer hope it will work

Comment: @Stardev i need $this-> region['klu'] in one title, $this->region['che'] in another, so i guess it's multiple rows.

Comment: What are the contents of the `r_alias` field in your row?

Comment: So you want to check if the `r_alias` field is equal to `klu`?

Comment: yes, if it's equal to klu and klu isset, then shot $this->region['klu']

Comment: please check the updated answer hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this

```
$data['region'] = Map_Model_Map_Factory::getFetchAll();
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($data['region']); // only for testing
$this->view->assign('region', $data);
```

Echo it in view

```
echo $region['klu'];
```

Comment: $this->region['klu'] - where klu - is a data in r_alias row in my table, can it find 'klu' in array?

Comment: 'region name for  klu' output - region['klu'] is empty (

Answer (score 1):

please try below code

```
static function getFetchAll()
    {
        $table = new Map_Model_Map_Table();
        $select = $table->select()
                        ->order('r_alias ASC');
        return $table->fetchAll($select).toArray();
    }
```

change your first line by below one

```
title="<?php echo (isset($this->region['r_alias']) && $this->region['r_alias']=='klu') ? $this->region['r_alias'] : 'region name for  klu'?>"
```

Comment: please print_r($region); and check is it giving correct values

Comment: it's okay:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [r_id] => 57 and etc.  [r_alias] => ad - this row i check in my if statement.

Comment: the deal is region['klu'] is not empty, but php can't find it